# How do I prevent Selenium Chrome webdriver from passing send_keys multiple times?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation

I'm learning web automation, and as a test case, I tried searching for a flight on expedia and passing date values into the given departure/return text boxes. For the first text box, everything is fine and send_keys works as expected, but for some reason for the second (or the return date text box), send_keys seems to pass both the previous date and the date that I want it to pass the second time around. If you run my code it is clear what happens, but here's a picture as well:

[image]

I don't know if this is simply because of the way expedia has their text boxes set up, or if I messed something up in my programming due to my inexperience, but assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my code so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='E:\Webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')

driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.get('https://www.expedia.com/')
driver.maximize_window()

driver.find_element_by_id('tab-flight-tab-hp').click() #clicks flight button
#driver.find_element(By.ID, 'tab-flight-tab-hp').click() can also be used to click flight button

time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_id('flight-origin-hp-flight').send_keys('NYC') #Origin
driver.find_element_by_id('flight-destination-hp-flight').send_keys('Toronto') #Destination


driver.find_element_by_id('flight-departing-hp-flight').clear()
driver.find_element_by_id('flight-departing-hp-flight').send_keys('12/28/2020') #Departing

time.sleep(1)

driver.find_element_by_id('flight-returning-hp-flight').clear()
driver.find_element_by_id('flight-returning-hp-flight').send_keys("01/15/2021")

time.sleep(5)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gcw-flights-form-hp-flight"]/div[8]/label/button').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

The site is configured to take return date same date as the departing date. Even if you are using *clear()* before sending keys, when you use *send_keys()* the command first clicks there. And it causes departing date to get entered. Followed by what you have passed in *send_keys()*
So what you can do is send backspace to clear date and then type the new returning date.

```
  back = Keys.BACK_SPACE * 10 #mm/dd/yyyy counts to 10 characters
  driver.find_element_by_id('flight-returning-hp-flight').send_keys(back + "01/15/2021")
```

That way, when the command encounters *send_keys()*, the departure date is entered by the site automatically and you send the backspace keys and then type the returning date. I hope that helps.